# How to create a Maven library (non-executable JAR)

Tags: java, maven

I am looking for a Git repo that I clone and get started on creating a simple library for Java/Maven. I assume I need to declare a mainClass which will be the interface to the library but I don't need to declare a main method? It's stupidly difficult to figure out how to create a library with Maven, I should be able to just clone a git repo skeleton project that has most things pre-configured?

So my question is - does anyone know of a good repo to clone that is a Maven library skeleton? Note that I not looking to create Maven plugin - just a library that uses Maven for dep management.

Comment: this looks close: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/

Comment: but mkyong's article is referring to "plugin" - I just want to create a library not a Maven plugin, and that article is from 2012.

Comment: You can check pretty every Git Java project that uses Maven like this one: https://github.com/is/jsch

Comment: @Ivan ironically that project was first published 7 years ago. It's been updated since, but I would love to see a Maven lib example that was initialized in the last 2 years.

Comment: If you are looking for a skeleton for a maven library then it doesn't matter when library was created. Moreover the whole skeleton consists of pom.xml, and 2 (or 4 folders) `src/main/java`, `src/test/java` (and optionally `src/main/resources` and `/src/test/resources`). All other stuff is specific for your actual project.

Comment: @Ivan I agree, I am just looking for a "modern" pom.xml file that I don't have to mess with much, with newer versions of everything or newer tools/plugins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have upload this repo for you. Its a very basic skeleton. Hope it helps you.

Basically it is a simple folder structure..

```
maven-library-skeleton
|
- src
     |
     - main
           |
           - java
- test
- pom.xml
```

pom.xml content is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.empty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-library-skeleton</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>>

    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Empty library</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>



    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>       

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Link to repository is: https://github.com/JosemyAB/maven-library-skeleton

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22078767)

Comment: nice thanks, if you could include build scripts (in bash) that would really round it out.  and a readme :)  If you title your repo "maven-library-skeleton", then I think people will know what it is

Comment: @SvenHarris i add more information to response. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Alexander Mils i rename the repo but i dont have enough time for create scripts. Feel free for add that you consider necessary. This is open source :). Consider mark the response as solution if you think its ok

Comment: to generate jar file, I needed to run `mvn package` after making this changes.

Answer (score 3):

The `<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>>` has an extra right angle bracket that will result in error.